# Why are the select option values invisible?

Tags: php, html, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out why all the values in the Select dropdown list are invisible. Here is what the json looks like:

```
[{"team_id":"1","team":"Golden State Warriors","sport":"NBA"},{"team_id":"2","team":"Los Angeles Lakers","sport":"NBA"},{"team_id":"3","team":"Los Angeles Clippers","sport":"NBA"}]
```

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
app.controller('getAllTeamsCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
{

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'getAllTeams.php'
    }).then(function getTeamsSuccessful(response) {
        $scope.listOfTeams = response.data;
        $scope.selectedTeam = null;

        console.log($scope.listOfTeams);

    }, function getTeamsError(response) {
        $scope.listOfTeams = response.statusText;
    }); // End of HTTP GET


}); // End AngularJS
```

And here is what my HTML looks like:

```
<body ng-controller="getAllTeamsCtrl">

<form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control"
                        ng-model="selectedTeam"
                        ng-options="item.team as item.team_name for item in listOfTeams">
                </select>
                <pre>selectedTeam : {{ selectedTeam | json }}</pre>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
<li ng-repeat="team in listOfTeams"> {{ team.team }} </li>

</body>
```

When I run this, I can click and bring down the dropdown list and when I click a value I can see what the team name is within the  tags but all the values within the list are invisible. Does this have something to do with Twitter Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the value as `team_name` and it doesn't exist, probably should be changed to `item.team_id`

Comment: That was it. Thank you!